# I couldn't reproduce the step 4 at codelab actions level 2 tutorial

Tags: actions-on-google

At codelab tutorial level2 "Build Actions for the Google Assistant (Level 2)" . (https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/actions-2/index.html#3)

I can't reproduce the expected output in simulator "Talk to my test app about banana".

I have an error : "Failed to parse Dialogflow response into AppResponse because of empty speech response."

Simulator :

[image: https://i.imgur.com/t5ukRbv.png]

I follow the same steps as the tutorial

Dialogflow :

[image: dialogflow]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you missed step 5 under "Define a custom fallback intent".

> We'll use the `@sys.any` entity to tell Dialogflow to generalize the
>   expression to any grammar (not just "banana"). Double-click on
>   "banana" and filter for or select `@sys.any`

The result should be that the "banana" training phrase will be highlighted and the color should match the `@sys.any` in the list of parameters.

[image]

This is causing the `any` parameter to never be populated, so the result phrase that uses `$any` is never used. Since there is no response that is valid, noneis returned.